# Understanding data recovery

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I recently learned an amazing fact via [*CompTIA Security+ Certification Guide, Meyers and Jernigan, 2nd edition*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/126002637X).

> "A good forensic examiner can recover the original data from a hard disk that’s been erased as many as nine times"

Curious to understand how this is possible, I looked into how erasing works.

At first sight, the fact above can be explained by the fact that "Most file systems only remove the link to data" ([Wikipedia's page on file erasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_deletion)). However, what I found most mystifying, is the following sentence: "But even overwriting parts of the disk with something else or formatting it may not guarantee that the sensitive data is completely unrecoverable". How can that be?

Comment: I understand your curiosity but this is no way some real issue or problem to be resolved. Thus an Off-topic question, here on this site. Please read [What topics I can Ask](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: "A good forensic examiner can recover the original data from a hard disk that’s been erased as many as nine times" define erased? If overwritten only once it is unrecoverable by Anyone.

Comment: "But even overwriting parts of the disk with something else or formatting it may not guarantee that the sensitive data is completely unrecoverable". How can that be?"  I suppose file fragments and other meta data will be left behind, If you Zero fill the entire drive absolutely nothing is recoverable.

Comment: [This link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58515/how-does-forensic-software-detect-deleted-files) may provide you with something as an answer.

Comment: C0deDaedalus, would you kindly clarify why the question is off-topic? I apologize if it is.

Comment: This might belong better in the skeptics SE as it may not be a valid statement. I'd read (unverified) that today's HD technology makes it impossible to recover after a single overwrite.

Comment: Start with [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_erasure). Then look at the requirements for military standard erasure [here](http://www.killdisk.com/dod.htm).

Comment: EmmanuelTsukerman it doesn't fall under the topics which @CodeDadalus linked. Not sure how much clearer they can be. We try to solve 'problems' here, not discuss things. As to your question - why '9' times? If this is 'real' then why doesn't everything just erase every file 10x to make sure?

Comment: djsmiley2k From the list of topics, computer hardware is listed. If you'd like, you can rephrase the question as a problem: "reconcile these seemingly contradictory facts". The fact that the question is apparently a duplicate lends credence to it being relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply as of the time that book was written, that statement is wrong.

It almost certainly comes from a misunderstanding if the seminal paper by Peter Gutmann and Colin Plumb - [“Secure Deletion of Data from Magnetic and Solid-State Memory”](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/secure_del.html) in July 1996. This paper defined how to securely erase data if you did not know the disk type in 1996 - 22 years ago.

Because of the densities involved a single pass of random data (maybe not even that - possibly all 0 or all 1) is all that's required to wipe a modern disk - assuming that you are needing to recover more then 8 BITS (1 byte) if data.

It is possible for fragments of data to be recoverable of they are part of a damaged disk - especially if data has been relocated/remapped. - which does happen.

Note: SSDs do remapping as a matter of course, and it is a lot harder to guarantee data is actually overwritten.